# Subprocess.Popen() working on terminal, not on VSCode

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run an executable file whose path I am providing in args of Popen() constructor. Following is the code I am trying to execute:

```
def callp(st):
    p = subprocess.Popen(st, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    p_status = p.wait()
    output=str(output)
    output = output.replace("\n", "|")
    output=output.replace('b\'','')
    output=output.replace('\'','')
    op=output.split('|')
    return(op[:-1])
```

Here, st contains the path to the executable file. This code works perfectly fine on Ubuntu Terminal, but the control returns back to the calling function in VSCode. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: `but the control returns back to the calling function in VSCode` ... how you call your python code into VStudio ?

Comment: I've made a separate python script and I import the callp() function in that script. I, then type [g, xrecent] = eval(callp(c)[:-1]) where c contains the path of the executable.